# saving file to firebase and the set the link in usestate but its not showing when saving in mongodb

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, firebase, firebase-storage

Basically the problem is my savedatatomongodb called before getting the url from the firebase.

How I can fix it?

I tried many things, but still not able to set the state before calling the function save_data_tomongodb.

I think some order of asynchronous function is wrong in my code.

```
//firebasedb
import storage from "../../../utils/firebase";
import {
  ref,
  uploadBytes,
  getDownloadURL,
  uploadBytesResumable,
} from "firebase/storage";

function CreateSong() {
  //
  const [cookies, setCookie] = useCookies(["token", "email"]);

  //for song name
  const [textField, setTextfeild] = useState(false);
  const [songname, setSongName] = useState("");
  const [songuploadProgress, setsongUploadProgress] = useState(0);
  const [songdownloadURL, setsongDownloadURL] = useState("");

  //for image upload

  const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(null);
  const [imguploadProgress, setimgUploadProgress] = useState(0);
  const [imgdownloadURL, setimgDownloadURL] = useState("");

  const handleImageChange = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];

    // Check if a file is selected
    if (file) {
      // Check if the selected file is an image
      if (isImageFile(file)) {
        // URL.createObjectURL(file)
        setSelectedImage(file);
        // Perform further actions with the image file if needed
      } else {
        console.log(
          "Invalid image file type. Please select a supported image file."
        );
      }
    }
  };

  const isImageFile = (file) => {
    // Add logic to check if the file type is an image file (e.g., JPEG, PNG, GIF, etc.)
    const allowedFileTypes = ["image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]; // Add more types as needed
    return allowedFileTypes.includes(file.type);
  };

  //for song upload using drag and drop
  const [song, setSong] = useState();
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);

  const handleMouseEnter = () => {
    setIsHovered(true);
  };

  const handleMouseLeave = () => {
    setIsHovered(false);
  };

  const [isDraggedOver, setIsDraggedOver] = useState(false);

  const handleDragEnter = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsDraggedOver(true);
  };

  const handleDragLeave = () => {
    setIsDraggedOver(false);
  };

  const handleDrop = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Handle the dropped file(s) here
    const files = e.dataTransfer.files;
    // Check if the dropped file is a music file (you can adjust the check based on your specific requirements)
    if (files.length == 1) {
      if (files.length > 0 && isMusicFile(files[0])) {
        console.log("Valid music file:", files[0]);
        setSong(files);

        // Perform further actions with the music file
      } else {
        console.log("Invalid file type. Please drop a music file.");
      }
      setIsDraggedOver(false);
    } else {
      console.log("Drop only one file");
    }
  };

  const isMusicFile = (file) => {
    // Add logic to check if the file type is a music file (e.g., MP3, WAV, etc.)
    const allowedFileTypes = ["audio/mpeg", "audio/wav"]; // Add more types as needed
    return allowedFileTypes.includes(file.type);
  };

  //save song and image in firebase functions

  //firebase setup

  **let uploadSong = async () => {
    if (song) {
      // Create a storage reference

      const songstorageRef = ref(storage, `/songs/${song.name}`);

      // Upload file
      const songuploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(songstorageRef, song);

      songuploadTask.on(
        "state_changed",
        (snapshot) => {
          const percent = Math.round(
            (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
          );

          // update progress
          setsongUploadProgress(percent);
        },
        (err) => console.log(err),
        async () => {
          // download url
          await getDownloadURL(songuploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((url) => {
            console.log({ songUrl: url });
            setsongDownloadURL(url);
          });
        }
      );
    } else {
      console.log("choose a song");
      return;
    }
  };

  let uploadImg = async () => {
    if (selectedImage) {
      // Create a storage reference

      const storageRef = ref(storage, `/images/${selectedImage.name}`);

      // Upload file
      const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, selectedImage);

      uploadTask.on(
        "state_changed",
        (snapshot) => {
          const percent = Math.round(
            (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
          );

          // update progress
          setimgUploadProgress(percent);
        },
        (err) => console.log(err),
        async () => {
          // download url
          await getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((url) => {
            console.log({ imgUrl: url });
            setimgDownloadURL(url);
          });
        }
      );
    }
  };

  const submitdata = async () => {
    try {
      await uploadSong();
      await uploadImg();
      await saveDataToMongo({ imgdownloadURL, songdownloadURL });

      console.log("Data saved to MongoDB");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  const saveDataToMongo = async (data) => {
    console.log(data);

    if (!imgdownloadURL || !songdownloadURL) {
      console.log("cant proceed" + imgdownloadURL);
      return;
    }
  };**
  return (
    <div
      className="song-uploadsection flex items-center gap-4"
      style={{
        background:
          "linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(28 28 28) 0%, rgb(43 41 41) 53%, rgb(73 73 73) 100%)",
      }}
    >
      <div className=" ">
        <label
          onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
          onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
          className="w-[200px] h-[200px] flex justify-center items-center bg-lightgray rounded-md mx-8 my-12"
          style={{
            boxShadow:
              "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 54px 55px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px -12px 30px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 4px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17) 0px 12px 13px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px -3px 5px",
          }}
          htmlFor="songImg"
        >
          <input
            className="hidden"
            type="file"
            name="songImg"
            id="songImg"
            accept="image/png, image/jpeg"
            onChange={handleImageChange}
          />

          {isHovered ? (
            <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center text-sm">
              <MdEdit className="w-[50px] h-[50px]" />
              <p className="text-center">Edit thumbnail</p>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center text-sm">
              {selectedImage ? (
                <img
                  src={selectedImage}
                  style={{ height: "200px", width: "200px" }}
                />
              ) : (
                <>
                  <FaMusic className="w-[50px] h-[50px]" />
                  <p className="text-center">
                    Drag and drop <br /> thumbnail
                  </p>
                </>
              )}
            </div>
          )}
        </label>
      </div>

      <div className="flex-1 cursor-default">
        <div>
          <div>
            <div
              className={`${
                isDraggedOver
                  ? "border-2 border-dashed border-white rounded-md p-4 mr-8 h-[200px] flex justify-center items-center"
                  : "flex flex-col justify-start"
              }`}
              onDragEnter={handleDragEnter}
              onDragOver={handleDragEnter}
              onDragLeave={handleDragLeave}
              onDrop={handleDrop}
            >
              {isDraggedOver ? (
                <h1 className="text-[5vw] font-robo font-bold text-primarytext">
                  Drop File Here...
                </h1>
              ) : (
                <>
                  <p>Song</p>
                  {textField ? (
                    <input
                      placeholder="Enter name"
                      className="bg-transparent text-[3rem] outline-none flex-1"
                      type="text"
                      name="songname"
                      id=""
                      value={songname}
                      onChange={(e) => {
                        setSongName(e.target.value);
                      }}
                    />
                  ) : (
                    <h1
                      onClick={() => {
                        setTextfeild(true);
                      }}
                      className="flex-1 text-[5vw] font-robo font-bold text-primarytext"
                    >
                      My Song#
                    </h1>
                  )}

                  <div className="flex gap-8 w-1/2">
                    <label htmlFor="songsFile">
                      <input
                        type="file"
                        name="songs"
                        id="songsFile"
                        className="hidden"
                        accept="audio/mp3, audio/wav"
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          if (e.target.files.length == 0) {
                            setSong((prevSong) => prevSong);
                          } else {
                            setSong(e.target.files[0]);
                          }
                        }}
                      />
                      <div
                        className={`flex gap-2 items-center w-fit px-4 py-2 rounded-full mt-4 border-[1px] ${
                          song
                            ? "text-green-500 border-green-500"
                            : "text-primarytext hover:text-white  border-primarytext hover:border-white"
                        }`}
                      >
                        {song ? (
                          <FaFileCircleCheck className="w-[25px] h-[25px] text-green-500" />
                        ) : (
                          <BsFileEarmarkMusicFill className="w-[25px] h-[25px]" />
                        )}

                        <p className="text-sm font-bold ">
                          {song ? "Change" : "Choose"} Song
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </label>
                    <button
                      onClick={submitdata}
                      className="flex gap-2 items-center w-fit px-8 py-2 rounded-full mt-4 bg-green-500 text-black font-bold hover:scale-105"
                    >
                      Upload
                    </button>
                  </div>

                  {/* progress  */}
                  <div className="imgprogress">
                    <h1>imageprogress</h1>
                    <p>{imguploadProgress}</p>
                    <h1>songprogress</h1>
                    <p>{songuploadProgress}</p>
                  </div>
                </>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CreateSong;
```

see my console I am getting the url but for function savedatatomongodb it is uundefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use React state to pass variables between functions in your code. It just complicates things and isn't needed. Instead use normal JavaScript variables, as I'll show below.

You can `await` the `uploadTask` to ensure the download is completed before `uploadImg` resolves.

```
let uploadImg = async () => {
  if (selectedImage) {
    // Create a storage reference

    const storageRef = ref(storage, `/images/${selectedImage.name}`);

    // Upload file
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, selectedImage);

    uploadTask.on(
      "state_changed",
      (snapshot) => {
        const percent = Math.round(
          (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
        );

        // update progress
        setimgUploadProgress(percent);
      },
      (err) => console.log(err),
      () => {
        //  This is no longer needed
      }
    );

    //  this is new code
    await uploadTask;
    const url = await getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref);
    return url;
  }
};
```

And then call it like this:

```
let downloadURL = await uploadImg();
await saveDataToMongo({ downloadURL, songdownloadURL });
```

Comment: Yes it worked when I also tried like this Thanks